# Is it possible to setup load balancing for 2 apps running on the same server?

Tags: iis, iis-7, load-balancing, arr

I have two instances of a web app (using play framework) running on the same machine under two different ports.
I am trying to work out if it is possible to set IIS to act as a reverse proxy and balance the request between the two apps.
So far I have only managed to rewrite to one application. I can't figure out how to do the load balancing between the two apps. I have tried to add a server farm but this only lets me define web apps on different servers.

Ps: the only reason to have to apps on the same machine is to allow transparent upgrades.

Tx.

Comment: I believe you can add the NLB role to the server and accomplish this.

Comment: It doesn't seem to let me add two clusters with the same ip address.

Comment: You would have to add at least one IP for each of the LB sites, a NLB vIP, and a management IP (off the top of my head, could be slightly wrong).

Comment: I think this is the main issue since I only have one server. I know that apache enables load balancing to the same ip address but on different ports.

Comment: That is true. But you didn't ask about Apache, you asked about IIS. It's possible to have multiple IPs on the same server you know.

Comment: The reference is because I am just porting the apps from apache as a reverse proxy to IIS and I am trying to emulate the config. So you reckon there is no way to load balance one IP with different ports but setting up 'virtual ips' could do the trick. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Try to assign 2 IPs to this machine and load balance it from there...

Comment: Anyway, I have a similar question over at http://serverfault.com/q/367124/206 . If you find an answer lemme know pls :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network Load Balancing (NLB) will allow you to load balance, so will Application Request Routing (ARR).

Both, however, are setup to route between two different servers, setting this up on 1 machine would not be possible.

NLB operates lower in the stack, and can load balance more than just IIS, whereas ARR is built into IIS and relies on URLRewrite to process requests.